# Grey screen while rendering

Tags: rendering

(First Post Here so sorry if I did something wrong while posting) I recently decided to render a car, but when I pressed the render button I was greeted with a Grey Screen. I've been to many other forums and tried their solutions but none of them worked. So I thought maybe I did something wrong and I decided to render the default cube in a new project and nope the same thing happened again.[image]

I tried reinstalling blender and even updating it from 2.82 to 2.83 but nothing worked. And before you ask, Yes the camera button in the layers menu has been selected. After a bit more digging around I found out that a project I made a few months ago might've been the cause for it because every other project before that one renders perfectly. But every project after that one gives me the grey screen.

Link to the project I want to render:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/1mjexg43uugbla3/Honda_Civic_2003AT.blend/file

Link to the project which I think might've caused a problem:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/u4rfu8i8hesxv2n/ElonHuman.blend/file

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Output* settings > *Post Processing*, you've enabled the *Compositor* option. If I take a look I see an *Image* node plugged into the *Composite* node. Plug an *Input > Render Layers* node instead and it works.

[image]